# How to join several tables to receive joint objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got Meeting, Project, Assignment and User objects.

**Meeting**

```
belongs_to :meetingable, polymorphic: true


 create_table "meetings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "meetingable_type"
    t.bigint "meetingable_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["meetingable_type", "meetingable_id"], name: "index_meetings_on_meetingable_type_and_meetingable_id"
  end
```

**Assignment**

```
belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true

create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "assignable_type"
    t.bigint "assignable_id"
    t.string "role", default: "owner"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["assignable_type", "assignable_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_assignable_type_and_assignable_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id"
  end
```

**User**

```
has_many :meetings, through: :assignments, source: :assignable, source_type: 'Meeting'

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**Project**

```
has_many :meetings, as: :meetingable, dependent: :destroy

create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

A Meeting belongs to a project with a polymorphic connection (assignable) and a User is assigned to a meeting using the Assignment table.

I know how to get all Meetings for a project like below but I also want to make sure the user calling for the list of Meetings is only receiving the ones that he och she is assigned to, how can I do this? I guess with some kind of join query but I am not proficient enough to construct one.

```
@project.meetings
```

The above query should only return meetings that are both connected to the Project (through polymorphic) and is assigned to the User (through Assignment table). I use the scenario in many other parts of my app so a generic solution would be great if possible.

I tried this but it does not feel like a good solution:

```
def index
        @output = current_user.meetings
        @output = @output.where(meetingable_id: params[:project_id], meetingable_type: params[:model_name])
    end
```

Thank you!

Comment: What relationships do you have in you models?

Comment: I have now updated the objects with their respective relevant relationships, thx!

Comment: Any ideas @BenTrewern?